# Function overloading using int and float type as an argument in c++

Tags: c++, floating-point, int, double, overloading

```
void sum(int x);
void sum(float x);
```

I don't understand why these function overloading statements create below error for `sum(2.3)`:

> call of overloaded `sum(double)` is ambiguous

But for the below two function overloading, it works well.

```
void sum(int x);
void sum(double x);
```

Comment: use `sum(2.3f)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2.3 is a double, and the compiler can't choose among converting to an int or to a float (both are subject to loss of precision).